# Quarkus Maven Plugin not building anymore

Tags: java, maven, quarkus

For some reason the backend of our Application does not build correctly:

### Error message

While using `mvn clean install` still works `mvn compile quarkus:dev -pl web` does not, throwing the following error message during the build of **quarkus-maven-plugin:1.11.3.Final:dev**:

```
10:26:50,438 WARN  [io.agr.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource '<default>': Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
10:26:50,440 WARN  [org.fly.cor.int.jdb.JdbcUtils] (Quarkus Main Thread) Connection error: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. (Caused by No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)) Retrying in 1 sec...
10:26:51,445 WARN  [io.agr.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource '<default>': Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
10:26:51,445 WARN  [org.fly.cor.int.jdb.JdbcUtils] (Quarkus Main Thread) Connection error: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. (Caused by No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)) Retrying in 2 sec...
10:26:53,450 WARN  [io.agr.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource '<default>': Communications link failure
```

This continues with increasing time intervals.

### Steps Taken

I already checked if the SQL Docker Container is offline, but it started as intended and is available using `telnet localhost 3306`.
Since the project is building as intended for my co-worker using the same commit, i tried a fresh install from our version control. To no avail.

The same project used to work correctly last week, with no changes to the project. The only system wide change applied in between is the installation of new nvidia drivers, cuda and cudNN. GPU drivers should not have any effect on a web app?

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before and knows how to mend it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had similar issues in the Quarkus CI and the fix was to update the MySQL container as the version used was too old and used ciphers that were not supported anymore by the JDK.

No common ciphers between the JDK and the MySQL instance can be found so things are not working properly.

Could you try to use a more recent version of the MySQL (or MariaDB) image? Typically the default one from Testcontainers is too old.

Comment: Thanks! Pushed the MySQL Version from 5.7.23 to 5.7.34 in our docker-compose, and voilà: the maven build is working again.